# Show that the difference between two simple functions functions gives the charachteristic function on some set

Tags: real-analysis

I suppose this this is simple, but I cannot verify it.

It is claimed that if

1) $0 \le s _1 \le s _2 ... \le f$

2) $s _n \to f$ pointwise

where $\{s _n \} $ is an sequence of measurable simple functions, and $0 \le f < 1 $, $f = 0 $ outside a compact set $A $.

then the funciton $2 ^n t _n = 2^n(s _n - s _{n-1 } ) $ (and $t _1 = s _1 $) is the 
charachteristic function of som set $T _n \subset A $,

Why should $s _n - s _{n-1 } = 1 /2 ^ {-n}  $ on some set , and zero outside it?

---

Take $x \in A$, then $s _n(x) = \alpha _i $ and $ s _{n-1 } (x)= \beta _i $, where $1>\alpha _i \ge \beta _i \ge 0$ , then what?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are missing some context. The $s_n$ you are looking at are defined in a certain way. This isn't generally true.

Comment: I thought so to! But this is from theorem 2.24 in Rudin's complex analysis, and I cannot find any more assumptions...

Comment: I have a copy of that book at hand. "Attach a sequence $\{s_n\}$ to $f$, **as in the proof of Theorem 1.17**..."

Comment: Yes, and not much more is said in 1.17!

Comment: A little bit more is said. For instance, the sequence $\{s_n\}$ is defined there.